# Spring XD properties-location attribute

Tags: spring-xd

I tried to create a stream with this definition:

```
stream create --name test3 --definition "jms  --destination=test3 --pubSub=true --subscriptionName=test3 --durableSubscription=true --clientId=cbda83 --outputType=text/plain | filter --script=file:/opt/bidpwr/app_config/spring_xd/fleet/startstop/ready1.groovy --properties-location=file:/opt/bidpwr/app_config/spring_xd/fleet/common/fleet_config.properties --inputType=application/json --outputType=application/json | log"
```

And it threw this error:

```
Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Error with option(s) for module filter of type processor:
    properties-location: option named 'properties-location' is not supported
```

I went through the documentation, but couldn't figure out why it's failing.

When I run `"info"`, I don't see the `--properties-location` attribute listed either:

```
xd:>module info processor:filter


Information about processor module 'filter':

  Option Name  Description                                                      Default  Type
  -----------  ---------------------------------------------------------------  -------  --------
  expression   a SpEL expression to evaluate as a predicate                     <none>   String
  script       location of a groovy script to use as a predicate to the filter  <none>   String
  outputType   how this module should emit messages it produces                 <none>   MimeType
  inputType    how this module should interpret messages it consumes            <none>   MimeType
```

Any idea how to solve this?